# Python - Adding all values of a list together but skipping strings

Tags: python, string, list, sorting

I have a list with mulitple lists in it. The lists in the main list contains both strings and integers. The list looks somewhat like this:

```
[['Flugt', 'DNS', '3', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['RaceTobi', '1', 'DNF', '3', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['cayre123', '2', '2', '8', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['Thomas222213', '4', '5', '5', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['Entity', '6', '1', '4', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['TheBiniz', '3', '4', '6', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['BWOAH STEERING WHEEL', '7', '6', '7', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['Blackreverse', '5', '7', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']]
```

The first object in the lists are a name for a specific player.

I now want to add all the integers in the small lists together and sort the lists with the one with the largest sum first, but i don't know how to do that when it contains strings aswell. Furthermore i want the name to still be the first string in the list. The data in the lists must be in the same order as it was to begin with, but the order in which they are placed in the main list must be by value

I hope it makes sense and that somebody can help me :)

Comment: Could you include some sample data?

Comment: Just added the data

Answer (score 0):

Use `sorted` with `lambda` sort by the `sum` of the `int` converted of items in your sublists that meet the condition `isdigit()`, use `reverse=True` for largest sublist first

```
lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: sum([int(i) for i in x if i.isdigit()]), reverse = True)
# [['BWOAH STEERING WHEEL', '7', '6', '7', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['Thomas222213', '4', '5', '5', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['Blackreverse', '5', '7', '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['TheBiniz', '3', '4', '6', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['cayre123', '2', '2', '8', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['Entity', '6', '1', '4', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['Flugt', 'DNS', '3', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['RaceTobi', '1', 'DNF', '3', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find out if a string is numeric as so:

```
"2".isnumeric()
# >>True
"hello".isnumeric()
# >>False
```

You can create a sublist of your inner lists by using list comprehension to pick out only the numeric strings

```
sub_inner_list = [i for i in inner_list if i.isnumeric()]
```

You can also convert these entries to integers in the same step and sum them.

```
sum_sub_inner_list = sum([int(i) for i in inner_list if i.isnumeric()])
```

This can be used as a key to sort your outer list, passing in the reversed=True option to sort by largest value first.

```
my_sorted_list = sorted(full_list, reverse=True, key=lambda inner: sum([int(i) for i in inner if i.isnumeric()]))
```